# How to arrange a paragraph over another?

Tags: html, css

I want to arrange the text of this site as well as in the picture below

```
http://i60.tinypic.com/aufae0.jpg
```

This is my site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/?page_id=14

This is code HTML:

```
<p id="text3">
    Am reprezentat şi am acordat consultanţă juridică pentru clienţi 

persoane fizice române şi străine, instituţii publice, persoane juridice 

române şi străine în următoarele domenii:
</p>

<br><br>

<p id="text4">

- agricultură, exploatări agricole, prelucrarea şi comercializarea 

produselor agricole;
<br>
- comerţ cu produse alimentare;
<br>
- imobiliar;
<br>
- distribuţie de carburanţi;
<br>
- transporturi;
<br>
- asigurări;
<br>
- producţie şi comercializare utilaje grele;
<br>
- producţie structuri metalice;
<br>
- producţie automatizări;
<br>
- servicii de proiectare;
<br>
- comercializare automatizări;
<br>
- jocuri de noroc;
<br>
- turism, hoteluri şi pensiuni;
<br>
- medical;
<br>
- construcţii civile şi industriale;
<br>
- comercializare utilaje şi autovehicule, service auto;
<br>
- producţie software, administrarea site-urilor;
<br>
- comerţ;
<br>
- bursier, societăţi listate, investitori, fonduri de investiţii.
<br>
- asistenţă şi îngrijire copii şi vârstnici;
<br>
- exploatări forestiere şi prelucrarea lemnului;
<br>
- exploatări agricole;
<br>
- extracţia şi prelucrarea minereurilor;
<br>
- producţia şi comercializarea materialelor de construcţii;
<br>
- instituţii publice;
<br>
- instituţii religioase.</p>
```

This code CSS:

```
    #text3{
    font-size: 17px;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    padding: 87px 45px 45px 20px;
    padding-left:50px;

}


#text4{
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    font-size:17px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s0bsfdu4/10/

The JS editor I managed to arrange text as they wish but I try to make changes on the site looks very ugly ...

Can you help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your end goal? Are you trying to add more padding between the columns? Are you trying to make more room between the left most column and the end of the page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6q54bhdx/ I tried this

Comment: So you want the left most column of text ontop of the right 2 columns?

Comment: Be aware that the CSS3 property "column-count" only works in IE 10+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may solve your problem by simply removing `width` and `float` like this:

```
#text3{
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 87px 45px 45px 20px;
    padding-left:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) from bootstrap to fix your text to the top?

Answer (score 0):

Right know i write from my mobilephone so I can't test code but here are some ideas:

Use a table with 2 columns and split the text in 2.

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>  first text part </td>
   <td>  second text part </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Table has many elements to set size, position, color, background.

You could also use 2 divs to make the same look

Comment: Yes you can split the text into 2 columns that way but that is not the correct way of going about it. Tables should be used to show data not make layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the text into a container. This is centered and a max width of 1200 or whatever you think looks good.

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Use box-sizing so the border doesn't effect the dimension

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Clearfloat after the div

```
.grid:after {
  /* Or @extend clearfix */
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Float all divs and add 0 padding to last column

```
[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.grid [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Column width

```
.col-1-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="container">
<p>Am reprezentat şi am acordat consultanţă juridică pentru clienţi persoane fizice române şi străine, instituţii publice, persoane juridice române şi străine în următoarele domenii:</p>

<div class="grid">
   <div class="col-1-2">
     <div class="module">
            <h3>1/2</h3>
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-1-2">
     <div class="module">
            <h3>1/2</h3>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I would also edit the list to not use < br >'s and start using lists.

Working jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/0dLeqg9s/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/0dLeqg9s/1/)

You can read more about it http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/